# One column data into multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am using SQL Server and I want to data according to `posid` in each column here is my code:

```
select ItcodedGrp,ItheadCat, ItheadCls,ItheadGrp,POsid,
(sum(OpnQty) + sum(FaultyQty) + sum(UsedQty) +  sum(RecQty) - sum(RejectQty)  - sum(Issued) + 
sum(DebitQty) + sum(AdjQty) + sum(STNQtyPls) - sum(STNQtyMin) - sum(POSQTY) - sum(TransitQty) - sum(FQtyMin)
+ sum(FQtyPlus) + sum(ReplaceQty)) as AllStock
from Vmgt_RSales_Stock
where POsid in   (2,6,7,10,11,12,13,14) and ItcodedGrp  like '28.01.059.%'
group by ItcodedGrp,ItheadCat, ItheadCls,ItheadGrp,POsid 
order by POsid asc
```

and here is my result.

I want the stock according to `posid` in each column

[image: pos wise stock in seaprate column]

as you can see in above image my stock is showing in front of `posid` but I want the all stock in column but `posid` wise like let me give you an example the how my result should be like the below

[image: Please see the below]

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation. Your `sum()` expression is lenghty so I would add one level of aggregation to avoid repeating it many times:

```
select
    ItcodedGrp,
    ItheadCat, 
    ItheadCls,
    ItheadGrp,
    sum(AllStock) AllStock,
    sum(case when POSid = 2  then AllStock end) POSid2,
    sum(case when POSid = 6  then AllStock end) POSid6,
    sum(case when POSid = 7  then AllStock end) POSid7,
    sum(case when POSid = 10 then AllStock end) POSid10,
    sum(case when POSid = 11 then AllStock end) POSid11,
    sum(case when POSid = 12 then AllStock end) POSid12,
    sum(case when POSid = 13 then AllStock end) POSid13,
    sum(case when POSid = 14 then AllStock end) POSid14
from (
    select 
        ItcodedGrp,
        ItheadCat, 
        ItheadCls,
        ItheadGrp,
        POsid,
        (
            sum(OpnQty) 
            + sum(FaultyQty) 
            + sum(UsedQty) 
            +  sum(RecQty) 
            - sum(RejectQty)  
            - sum(Issued) 
            + sum(DebitQty) 
            + sum(AdjQty) 
            + sum(STNQtyPls) 
            - sum(STNQtyMin) 
            - sum(POSQTY) 
            - sum(TransitQty) 
            - sum(FQtyMin)
            + sum(FQtyPlus) 
            + sum(ReplaceQty)
        ) as AllStock
    from Vmgt_RSales_Stock
    where 
        POsid in (2,6,7,10,11,12,13,14) 
        and ItcodedGrp  like '28.01.059.%'
    group by 
        ItcodedGrp,
        ItheadCat, 
        ItheadCls,
        ItheadGrp,
        POsid 
    ) t
group by 
    tcodedGrp,
    ItheadCat, 
    ItheadCls,
    ItheadGrp
```

Comment: Oh MY god its solve my question thank you so much Dear GMB !!!

Comment: @MakhdoomLiaqat Yes, Accepting answer is the only return for the help.